# Css card not resizing when text increases

Tags: html, css

I am designing a pricing page.

If I increase the text the card will not expand, making it look like this:

[image]

```css
.pricing-box {
  margin: 5rem 0rem;
}

.pricing-box header {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.pricing-box .card-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.pricing-box .card-container .card:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-left: 0px;
  box-shadow: none;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  z-index: 2;
}

.pricing-box .card-container .card {
  width: 100%;
}

.pricing-box .card-container ul {
  margin: 2.6px;
}

.pricing-box .card-container ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.pricing-box .card-container ul li.price {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricing-box">
  <header>
    <h1>Our Pricing</h1>
  </header>


  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card shadow">
      <ul>
        <li class="pack">Basic</li>
        <li id="basic" class="price bottom-bar">
          $dollar; 199.99
        </li>
        <li class="bottom bar">5600 GB Storage</li>
        <li class="bottom bar">2 Users Allowed</li>
        <li class="bottom bar">Send up to 3 GB</li>
        <li>
          <button class="btn">Learn More</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I centered the card using flex, and I tried to increase the size of the text and found that the card does not resize to accommodate the text while I tried to increase the size of the text.

Comment: Change `$dollar;` to `&dollar;` in your html. Also which text size you are trying to increase?

Comment: @Usaid I am trying to increase the size of the price

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error with the css you provided. Try removing `width: 100%` from `.pricing-box .card-container .card` class.

Comment: While I took a moment to convert your posted code into a runnable snippet, you haven't provided enough code to reproduce your displayed output, could you add that CSS (and of course remove any unnecessary code)?

Comment: @DavidThomas I believe he is using bootstrap, so i think he didn't know he could've added the library to the snippet. About what etranz's question, can the containers have different sizes? Or you want them to have the same size independent of the content inside?

Comment: @manjirosano: I did think that was likely, but I didn't want to change the code on that assumption, which is why I'm asking for etranz to update the code instead of doing it myself :)

Comment: @DavidThomas That's a fair point. Well, I think we don't really need to achieve that UI specifically, I think we just need to know if the containers can or not have different sizes, and based on the answer, we could give the information he needs, because we even have the class of the card container with some styling already

Comment: Just to add to the comments above, not withstanding the incomplete code/css, if your price is wrapping and you don't want it to then add `#basic {  white-space: nowrap; }` to your css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the pricing card is already set to be 100% width, so increasing the text should not cause the card to expand. However, if the text becomes too long, it might overflow and cause layout issues.

To avoid this, you can set a maximum width for the pricing card and add text-overflow and overflow properties to the price element to handle long prices.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Pricing Page</title>
  <style>
    .pricing-box {
      margin: 5rem 0rem;
    }
    
    .pricing-box header {
      margin-bottom: 2rem;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .pricing-box .card-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      width: 100%;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .pricing-box .card-container .card:nth-of-type(2) {
      margin-left: 0px;
      box-shadow: none;
      transform: scale(1.1);
      z-index: 2;
    }
    
    .pricing-box .card-container .card {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 400px;
    }
    
    .pricing-box .card-container ul {
      margin: 2.6px;
    }
    
    .pricing-box .card-container ul li {
      list-style: none;
      margin-top: 1rem;
    }
    
    .pricing-box .card-container ul li.price {
      font-size: 3rem;
      max-width: 100%;
      /* allow the price element to take up the full width of the card */
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      /* add an ellipsis if the price overflows */
      overflow: hidden;
      /* hide the overflow of the price element */
    }
    
    .btn {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 12px 30px;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    
    .btn:hover {
      background-color: #3e8e41;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="pricing-box">
    <header>
      <h1>Our Pricing</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="card-container">
      <div class="card shadow">
        <ul>
          <li class="pack">Basic</li>
          <li id="basic" class="price bottom-bar">
            $dollar; 199.99 per month
          </li>
          <li class="bottom bar">5600 GB Storage</li>
          <li class="bottom bar">2 Users Allowed</li>
          <li class="bottom bar">Send up to 3 GB</li>
          <li>
            <button class="btn">Learn More</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope this answer is helpful to you.